# How to add a virtual keyboard supporting Japenese (Hiragana) language using jquery plugin?

Tags: virtual-keyboard

Is there any plugin to implement Japanese (Hiragana only) virtual keyboard using JQuery plugin?

The virtual keyboard should pop up on textbox click.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard

Comment: @Mottie, hello, I am using your projectl however, I just want Japanese. When I run the project it says ' $(...).keyboard(...).addTyping is not a function'.. Any idea why?

Comment: I posted a working demo in my answer. If you're still having issues, make sure you're loading jQuery first, and only one time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick demo of setting up the keyboard ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/d6k2vr8z/1/))

Make sure to load in, along with the css & keyboard files (look at the resources tab in the demo)

- https://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/languages/ja.untranslated.js (please help translate this file if would)
- https://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/layouts/keyboard-layouts-microsoft.js, or https://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/layouts/keyboard-layouts-greywyvern.js

  If these two files are a bit too big, since you only want one layout, then you can load in this file - https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/blob/master/layouts/ms-Japanese-Hiragana.js - or copy/paste it directly into your code

Then initialize the keyboard as follows:

```
$(function() {
  $('#keyboard').keyboard({
    language: ['ja'],
    layout: 'ms-Japanese Hiragana', // or "ja" for the greywyvern version
  });
});
```